# Обновление объекта

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

помогите пожалуйста. Есть 2 массива, один с объектами другой числовой. В числовом хранятся `number` из массива с объектами.

Как мне правильно найти посредством числового массива индекс объекта и изменить в объекте `selected: true`?

Сейчас с `newArr` происходит чудо, но сам `arr` меняет значение `selected`

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'Hello',
  selected: false,
  number: 14
}, {
  name: 'World',
  selected: false,
  number: 18
}, {
  name: '!',
  selected: false,
  number: 31
}]

var numbers = [14, 31];

var newArr = arr.map((item, index) => numbers.map((number) => item.number == number ? arr[index].selected = true : arr[index]))

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нужно понимать несколько вещей:

- map получает на вход массив и возвращает новый массив
- если элементом исходного массива был объект то он будет передан по ссылке (то есть item и arr[index] - суть один и тот же объект)
- стрелочная функция в неблочном виде возвращает результат последней операции.

Чудеса стали возможны потому, что не были учтены базовые особенности map и стрелочных функций. Ну и явно не является эффективным решением перебор массива numbers для каждого элемента массива arr.

Из вопроса не совсем понятно какой именно вы хотите получить результат по этому продемонстрирую 3 (более эффективных) варианта:

- изменяем selected в arr
- создаём newArr из объектов массива arr
- создаём newArr из копий объектов массива arr.

Поехали!

*Изменяем selected в arr*:

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Hello', number: 14}, {name: 'World', number: 18}, {name: '!', number: 31}];

var numbers = [14, 31];

arr.forEach(x => x.selected = numbers.indexOf(x.number) > -1);

console.log(arr);
```

*Cоздаём newArr из объектов массива arr*:

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Hello', number: 14}, {name: 'World', number: 18}, {name: '!', number: 31}];

var numbers = [14, 31];

var newArr = arr.map(x => {
                  x.selected = numbers.indexOf(x.number) > -1;
                  return x;
             });

console.log(newArr);
console.log(arr);
```

*Cоздаём newArr из копий объектов массива arr*:

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Hello', number: 14}, {name: 'World', number: 18}, {name: '!', number: 31}];

var numbers = [14, 31];

var newArr1 = arr.map(x => {
                  var o = Object.assign({}, x);
                  o.selected = numbers.indexOf(o.number) > -1;
                  return o;
             });
var newArr2 = arr.map(x => Object.assign({selected: (numbers.indexOf(x.number) > -1)}, x));
var newArr3 = arr.map(x => {
                return { ...x , selected: (numbers.indexOf(x.number) > -1) };
});

console.log(newArr2);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: у меня в примере возвращается данные в `newArr`

Comment: @Puvvl, я писал ответ в дороге и собираюсь сейчас расширить его

Comment: @Puvvl теперь задавай свои ответы

Comment: 2-рой вариант очень хорош. Поменял бы `numbers.indexOf(o.number) > -1` на `numbers.includes(o.number)`. Спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом:

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'Hello',
  selected: false,
  number: 14
}, {
  name: 'World',
  selected: false,
  number: 18
}, {
  name: '!',
  selected: false,
  number: 31
}]

var numbers = [14, 31];

var newArr = arr.map((item, index) => {
  numbers.map((number) => { if (item.number == number)   arr[index].selected = true; return arr[index];}); return item;} );

console.log(newArr)
```